# Number of permutations where an element must precede another

Tags: permutations, combinations

http://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/2013/zio2013/zio2013-qpaper.pdf

The fourth question. Can anyone explain how to solve it?

I need to calculate the number of permutations possible while making sure that certain numbers appear in a certain order which I have no clue how to do.

There is a number of tasks and some of the tasks depend on previous ones so can't be completed without completing those before it. For example we have task 1 to 4 where 4 depends on 2 and 3 and 3 depends on 1. Then the possible ways to do it would 1,2,3,4 2,1,3,4 2,3,1,4 but not 3,1,2,4.

So I need to calculate the number of ways in which the tasks can be done.

$$\begin{array}{|l|c|} \hline
\text{Task Number} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\ \hline
\text{Depends on} & - & 1 & 2 & - & 4 & 3,5 & 6 & 7 & 6 & 9 & 8,10 & 11 & 11 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: Please don't post questions where the actual question is only linked. Edit and add the actual question to your question.

Answer (score 1):

In each case here, the dependencies form a poset (partially ordered set) with a few elements which are comparable to all the rest. We know where these elements must go, which greatly cuts down on the possibilities.

For instance, the first case given has this poset:

[image]

So the tasks must be ordered with 1 first, then (2345) in some order, then 6, then (789) in some order, and finally 10 last.
For (2345), we know the order 2 and 3 come in, and the order of 4 and 5, so we must only choose which two of the four spots are occupied by 4 and 5: there are $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ ways.
Similarly, there are $\binom{3}{1} = 3$ ways to order 7, 8, and 9,
for a total of 18 possible orders of the tasks.

The second case has this poset:

[image]

The tasks come in the order (1,2,3,4,5)6(7,8,9,10)11(12,13), where the parentheses denote tasks which can be rearranged among themselves.
There are $\binom{5}{2} \binom{4}{2} \binom{2}{1} = 120$ possible orderings.

The third case has this poset:

[image]

There are $3! \binom{2}{1} \binom{6}{3} = 240$ possible orders.

Comment: "For (2345), we know the order 2 and 3 come in, and the order of 4 and 5, so we must only choose which two of the four spots are occupied by 4 and 5". Sorry, wasn't able to understand this.

Comment: Consider your four blanks, _ _ _ _.  If you know that 4 and 5 appear in the first two spots: * * _ _, then the only allowed order is 4 5 2 3. If you know that 4 and 5 are in these two spots: _ * _ *, then the order is 2 4 3 5. So choosing two spots completely determines the order. @archti

Answer (score 0):

You could start by drawing a dependency graph. This would show you, for example, that task 6 has to occur after tasks 1-5 and before tasks 7-13. This is very useful because those two parts can then be considered separately, and the result multiplied together at the end.

At the front end, task 1-2-3 form a sequence and task 4-5 also. These two sequences can be interleaved in a number of ways equivalent to allocating 2 items into 4 categories (or 3 into 3) resulting in ${5 \choose 2}$ options.

I'll come back to the back end later, when you've had a chance to try this out...

Comment: I figured that out when solving the first part which I did through brute force. What I couldn't understand is why 5C2 options would be there.

Comment: That's "stars&bars", the way for using selection to allocate items into defined categories. Essentially you add k-1 items to your set then use selection to turn k-1 items into category dividers. So putting 3 items \*\*\* into 3 categories ?|?|?, add 2 items \*\*\*\*\* then choose 2 items to turn into dividers. \*|\*\*|

Comment: @archti In this case you don't even need to think about stars&bars, though. You know there are 5 activities, 3 on one path and two on the other. so you're just choosing when the second-path activities occur in the sequence.